# Use different databases based on URL rewrite rule for .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am developing a multi-tenant SaaS application. Each tenant has its own database. All tenant-specific data is confined to the tenant’s database and isolated from other tenants and their data. I do have centralized tenants’ metadata dictionary with information that allows connections to the tenant’s database.

Each tenant has got their unique username and will be able to access the application using a url structure such as  **abc.domain.com/username**. I would like to connect to the tenants database depending upon username in the url.

Answer (score 0):

You could direct all traffic to a single php file that handles all the urls

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

Then, in index.php you would get the request url and parse it.

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
preg_match('|^/([^/]+)|', $uri, $matches);
$username = $matches[1];
```

If I did it this way, I'd also have a central database with a table consisting all existing users and their corresponding database names. I'd use $username to find the corresponding database name.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the url to put the tenant as a query parameter.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/(.*)$ /$2?tenant=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will let you connect to this database with

```
$tenant = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'tenant', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$metadata   = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=meta', $user, $pass);
$tenantdata = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $tenant, 
$_SESSION['tenantpass']);
$tenantdata->prepare('SELECT foo FROM bar');
...
```